# How to flatten nested arrays and remove empty arrays only if they are nested using MongoDB aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to transform my documents as shown below. I've tried using the `$unwind` operator, then the `$group` operator combined with the `$push` operator to re-build the `$user_mentions` array, but this also pushes all of the empty arrays and I'm back to square one again.

What I start with:

```
{
  _id: "6222407",
  name: "Chris",
  user_mentions: [
    [],
    [{_id:"963222", name: "Bob"}, {_id:"234324", name: "Fred"}]
  ]
},
{
  _id: "34566",
  name: "Tim",
  user_mentions: [
    []
  ]
},
{
  _id: "65343",
  name: "Sean",
  user_mentions: [
    [],
    []
  ]
}
}
```

What I want:

```
{
  _id: "6222407",
  name: "Chris",
  user_mentions: [
    {_id:"963222", name: "Bob"}, 
    {_id:"234324", name: "Fred"}]
  ]
},
{
  _id: "34566",
  name: "Tim",
  user_mentions: [

  ]
},
{
  _id: "65343",
  name: "Sean",
  user_mentions: [

  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the nature of your document layout you have to unwind twice (array in array). Also use the [preserveNullAndEmptyArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on the second unwind to keep empty array's in the documents.

Here's the aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $unwind: "$user_mentions"
    },
    {
      $unwind: { path: "$user_mentions", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }
    },
    {
      $group: {
      _id : "$_id",
      name : {$first : "$name"},
      user_mentions : { $push : "$user_mentions"}
      }
    }
  ]    
);
```

Comment: This LOOKS like it's what I want. :) I'm getting 3.2 I to test that second $unwind's functionality..

Comment: For others reading: You will need MongoDB version 3.2. I had trouble getting 3.2 to run properly on Ubuntu 14.04 but luckily had a Windows PC too.

Comment: When you want it on a pre 3.2 MongoDB, you can add a project stage with a $cond to create a empty array when none is present. When required i can add an example to the answer.